# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI for my case

Tags: java, html, spring, tomcat

My case is:
I have a homepage, there is a link called "sign in" on my homepage, when I clicked the "sign in" link, the browser shows "HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]".
what I want is: when I click the "sign in" link, I want the website direct to a new page which is the login page. Thank you!

homepage.jsp:

```html
<li><a class="drop" href="#">My Account</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="login.html">Sign In</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Create Account</a>></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
```

web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   version="3.0">
  <display-name>TooO</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>homepage.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

login-servlet.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
     
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
 
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
 
    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crunchify.controller" />
</beans:beans>
```

LoginController.java:

```js
package com.crunchify.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String init(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Please Enter Your Login Details");
        return "login";
    }
 
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(Model model, @ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean) {
        if (loginBean != null && loginBean.getUserName() != null & loginBean.getPassword() != null) {
            if (loginBean.getUserName().equals("chandra") && loginBean.getPassword().equals("chandra123")) {
                model.addAttribute("msg", "welcome" + loginBean.getUserName());
                return "success";
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid Details");
                return "login";
            }
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Please enter Details");
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of the 404 error web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPCbE.png)

Comment: At first delete the .html from your link<li><a href="login">Sign In</a></li>
 and change your login page to .jsp because your suffix handling ".jsp" pages.

Comment: Add somePath to your post method like @PostMapping("/submit")

Comment: Can you show me  the link that cause 404?

Comment: I just attached the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize *two* Spring Servlets - that's not the way it works.

Make it one SpringDispatcher only and assign a URL pattern that's simple

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/crunch/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now all calls to somethin like crunch/* will be directed into Spring.

Given your @RequestMapping in your LoginController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String init(Model model) {
```

This would now result into the following URL to actually reach the login controller:

```
/crunch/login
   ^      ^
   |      will be routed into LoginController by Spring
   will be routed to Spring by Servlet Container
```

now modify your login link accordingly:

```
   <ul>
      <li><a href="crunch/login">Sign In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Create Account</a>></li>
   </ul>
```

And give it another try.